# apache taking old openssl libraries when doing apachectl graceful

Tags: apache-2.4, freebsd, openssl, heartbleed, libraries

Due to heartbleed vulnerability I have recompiled apache with non vulnerable latest openssl(I had to keep old vulnerable openssl due to some dependency problem). It is running fine and when doing heartbleed test for mydomain.com it says 'seems fixed or unaffected'. But if I do `apachectl graceful` and take test for heartbleed it says mydomain.com is vulnerable. If I do `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache2 restart` or `apachectl restart` there is no problem.

1)My question is why it takes old openssl library when doing `apachectl graceful` only?

2)What is the difference between `apachectl restart` and `apachectl graceful` when accessing openssl libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `apachectl restart` and `graceful` in terms of loading libraries.  `apachectl graceful` sends the SIGUSR1 signal instead of SIGTERM so that open connections have the oppurtunity to close instead of being interrupted. see [apachectl man page](http://www.skrenta.com/rt/man/apachectl.8.html)

You may have 2 installations of apache on your system.  If apache was installed through your package manager and you didn't remove it before you recompiled then that could explain the bizarre test results.  You could be starting apache with `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/apache2 restart` which would start your recompiled instance.  Then when you used `apachectl` which is really `/usr/sbin/apachectl` it started your vulnerable installation and you failed the check.

Comment: Wrong. apachectl restart start new version (non vulnerable), but apachectl graceful is vulnerable.

Comment: @Harikrishnan when apache fails the test, if you run `ps aux | egrep "(httpd|apache)"` is your new binary is what is shown by ps?

Comment: yes..it's new binary but with old openssl.(Old binary is moved from default path)

Comment: In your httpd.conf, does `LoadModule ssl_module [path to module]` point to the new module?